# I have to change the date format of material range date picker

Tags: java, android

I am using range date picker to get start date and end date... can you please help me to change formatting of date **dd/mm/yyyy** to **mm/dd/yyyy** and store it into 2 different variables for start date and end date.

```
 MaterialDatePicker materialDatePicker= MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
                   .setSelection(Pair.create(thisMonthInUtcMilliseconds(), todayInUtcMilliseconds()))
                   .build();


 materialDatePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "MATERIAL_DATE_PICKER");
                    materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener<Long>() {
                        @Override public void onPositiveButtonClick(Long selection) {
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                            calendar.setTimeInMillis(selection);
                            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd");
                            String formattedDate  = format.format(calendar.getTime());


                            Toast.makeText(ManageCustomerByAgent.this, materialDatePicker.getHeaderText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            CustomerCreationFromDate.setText( materialDatePicker.getHeaderText());
                        }
                    });
```

i got error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.core.util.Pair cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
        at com.sarvodaya.tagjee.IDBI.IDBIAgent.ManageCustomerByAgent$ManageFPCustomerFilter$1.onPositiveButtonClick(ManageCustomerByAgent.java:1507)
        at com.google.android.material.datepicker.MaterialDatePicker$1.onClick(MaterialDatePicker.java:249)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain the accurate callback value type, it is necessary to update the override method.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd");

materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener<Pair<Long, Long>>() {
      @Override public void onPositiveButtonClick(Pair<Long,Long> selection) {
           Date startDate = new Date(selection.first);
           String startDateString = format.format(startDate);

      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you created your picker with the class `Pair` (`.setSelection(Pair.create(thisMonthInUtcMilliseconds(), todayInUtcMilliseconds()))`), you have to implement the method `onPositiveButtonClick(..)` alse with the class `Pair` as parameter:

```
onPositiveButtonClick(Pair selection)
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but it not works... this method only accept Object as parameter.

Comment: *this method only accept Object as parameter.* In your code you have a Long, so it can not accept an object only?